# How to filter timestamps of one data frame based on timestamps from another?

Tags: r, time, filter, move

I am attempting to filter one dataframe 'Blond_GSE' e.g. (bird tracking data which contains lots of variables including a timestamp) by the timestamps from a separate dataframe 'Blond_Prey' (variables including a timestamp of when a bird bought food to a nest) .

I would like to filter, so I have a new data frame with all tracking data (Blond_GSE) 30 minutes prior to the timestamps from the 'Blond_Prey.

Here is a look at each separate data frame.

```
head(Blond_GSE)

tag_id sensor_type_id acceleration_raw_x acceleration_raw_y
1 977476871            653                 30               -942
2 977476871            653                 32               -949
3 977476871            653                 34               -949
4 977476871            653                 40               -944
5 977476871            653                 36               -943
6 977476871            653                 36               -944
acceleration_raw_z barometric_height battery_charge_percent
1                454                 0                    100
2                445                 0                    100
3                450                 0                    100
4                446                 0                    100
5                451                 0                    100
6                455                 0                    100
battery_charging_current external_temperature flt_switch gps_hdop
1                        0                   33         NA      0.9
2                        0                   33         NA      1.0
3                        0                   33         NA      1.0
4                        0                   34         NA      0.9
5                        0                   33         NA      1.0
6                        0                   33         NA      0.8
gps_maximum_signal_strength gps_satellite_count gps_time_to_fix
1                          NA                   7           21.46
2                          NA                   6           12.48
3                          NA                   7           14.48
4                          NA                   8           26.41
5                          NA                   7            7.95
6                          NA                   9            8.98
ground_speed gsm_mcc_mnc heading height_above_ellipsoid
1            0          NA      86                     NA
2            0          NA     296                     NA
3            0          NA     331                     NA
4            0          NA      44                     NA
5            0          NA     213                     NA
6            0          NA     225                     NA
height_above_msl import_marked_outlier light_level
1              152                 false           0
2              152                 false           0
3              152                 false           0
4              152                 false           0
5              152                 false           0
6              152                 false           0
location_error_numerical location_lat location_long
1                       NA     51.86663      27.59045
2                       NA     51.86654      27.59053
3                       NA     51.86645      27.59056
4                       NA     51.86644      27.59071
5                       NA     51.86636      27.59047
6                       NA     51.86646      27.59067
magnetic_field_raw_x magnetic_field_raw_y magnetic_field_raw_z
1                0.067               -0.354               -0.024
2                0.065               -0.360               -0.013
3                0.067               -0.352               -0.019
4                0.061               -0.360               -0.012
5                0.061               -0.356               -0.014
6                0.073               -0.350               -0.019
ornitela_transmission_protocol tag_voltage           timestamp
1                           GPRS        4155 2019-04-26 01:42:00
2                           GPRS        4150 2019-04-26 01:46:51
3                           GPRS        4150 2019-04-26 01:51:53
4                           GPRS        4150 2019-04-26 01:57:05
5                           GPRS        4147 2019-04-26 02:01:46
6                           GPRS        4147 2019-04-26 02:06:47
transmission_timestamp               update_ts
1                        2019-10-07 09:46:52.104
2                        2019-10-07 09:46:52.104
3                        2019-10-07 09:46:52.104
4                        2019-10-07 09:46:52.104
5                        2019-10-07 09:46:52.104
6                        2019-10-07 09:46:52.104
vertical_error_numerical visible deployment_id    event_id
1                       NA    true    1003456347 12506913411
2                       NA    true    1003456347 12506913412
3                       NA    true    1003456347 12506913413
4                       NA    true    1003456347 12506913414
5                       NA    true    1003456347 12506913415
6                       NA    true    1003456347 12506913416
sensor_type tag_local_identifier location_long.1 location_lat.1
1         GPS               171035        27.59045       51.86663
2         GPS               171035        27.59053       51.86654
3         GPS               171035        27.59056       51.86645
4         GPS               171035        27.59071       51.86644
5         GPS               171035        27.59047       51.86636
6         GPS               171035        27.59067       51.86646
optional sensor          timestamps trackId comments
1     TRUE    GPS 2019-04-26 01:42:00   Blond       NA
2     TRUE    GPS 2019-04-26 01:46:51   Blond       NA
3     TRUE    GPS 2019-04-26 01:51:53   Blond       NA
4     TRUE    GPS 2019-04-26 01:57:05   Blond       NA
5     TRUE    GPS 2019-04-26 02:01:46   Blond       NA
6     TRUE    GPS 2019-04-26 02:06:47   Blond       NA
death_comments earliest_date_born exact_date_of_birth
1                                NA                    
2                                NA                    
3                                NA                    
4                                NA                    
5                                NA                    
6                                NA                    
individual_id latest_date_born local_identifier nick_name ring_id
1    1003455374               NA            Blond     Blond        
2    1003455374               NA            Blond     Blond        
3    1003455374               NA            Blond     Blond        
4    1003455374               NA            Blond     Blond        
5    1003455374               NA            Blond     Blond        
6    1003455374               NA            Blond     Blond        
sex taxon_canonical_name         timestamp_start
1            Aquila clanga 2018-08-31 00:01:23.000
2            Aquila clanga 2018-08-31 00:01:23.000
3            Aquila clanga 2018-08-31 00:01:23.000
4            Aquila clanga 2018-08-31 00:01:23.000
5            Aquila clanga 2018-08-31 00:01:23.000
6            Aquila clanga 2018-08-31 00:01:23.000
timestamp_end number_of_events number_of_deployments
1 2020-07-16 09:54:12.000            85156                     1
2 2020-07-16 09:54:12.000            85156                     1
3 2020-07-16 09:54:12.000            85156                     1
4 2020-07-16 09:54:12.000            85156                     1
5 2020-07-16 09:54:12.000            85156                     1
6 2020-07-16 09:54:12.000            85156                     1
sensor_type_ids  taxon_detail
1             GPS Clanga clanga
2             GPS Clanga clanga
3             GPS Clanga clanga
4             GPS Clanga clanga
5             GPS Clanga clanga
6             GPS Clanga clanga


head(Blond_prey)


Location    ID Species  Habitat Year       Date Activity Gender
1   ?????? Blond      BP Fen Mire 2019 2019-04-25  Arrival      M
2   ?????? Blond      BP Fen Mire 2019 2019-04-27  Arrival      M
3   ?????? Blond      BP Fen Mire 2019 2019-04-27  Arrival      M
4   ?????? Blond      BP Fen Mire 2019 2019-05-03  Arrival      M
5   ?????? Blond      BP Fen Mire 2019 2019-05-12  Arrival      M
6   ?????? Blond      BP Fen Mire 2019 2019-05-13  Arrival      M
Activity_1   Category                            Prey
1 Prey Delivery           ? medium-sized bird or large vole
2 Prey Delivery           ?                 Something Small
3 Prey Delivery  Crane-like                   Spotted Crake
4 Prey Delivery       Geese                      Large Duck
5 Prey Delivery           ? medium-sized bird or large vole
6 Prey Delivery       Snake                     Grass Snake
Class  Age            Condition Weight..g.            Notes
1        ? <NA>                 <NA>        100 Imperfectly Seen
2        ? <NA>                 <NA>         NA             <NA>
  3     Aves   ad                 <NA>         NA             <NA>
  4     Aves   ad duck spine with head         NA             <NA>
  5        ? <NA>                 <NA>        100 Imperfectly Seen
6 Reptilia <NA>                 <NA>         NA             <NA>
  New_Time
1 2019-04-25 17:03:00 UTC
2 2019-04-27 04:39:00 UTC
3 2019-04-27 07:33:00 UTC
4 2019-05-03 07:26:00 UTC
5 2019-05-12 06:40:00 UTC
6 2019-05-13 13:19:00 UTC
```

The columns with the timestamps are called "timestamp" in Blond_GSE and "New_Time in Blond_Prey.
Here are a look at the two timestamps.

```
head(Blond_GSE$timestamp)
[1] "2019-04-26 01:42:00 UTC" "2019-04-26 01:46:51 UTC"
[3] "2019-04-26 01:51:53 UTC" "2019-04-26 01:57:05 UTC"
[5] "2019-04-26 02:01:46 UTC" "2019-04-26 02:06:47 UTC"

head(Blond_prey$New_Time)
[1] "2019-04-25 17:03:00 UTC" "2019-04-27 04:39:00 UTC"
[3] "2019-04-27 07:33:00 UTC" "2019-05-03 07:26:00 UTC"
[5] "2019-05-12 06:40:00 UTC" "2019-05-13 13:19:00 UTC"
```

I would like to filter the Blond_GSE data by the timestamp of Blond_prey, so I get all data 30 mins prior to the Blond_Prey timestamps.

Is this possible?

I have tried the code.

```
 Blond.GSE <- Blond_GSE %>% filter_time(timestamp => Blond_prey$New_Time <=(Blond_prey&New_Time - 30))
```

However that returns an error message:

> Error: unexpected '>' in "Blond.GSE <- Blond_GSE %>% filter_time(timestamp =>"

Please can someone help?

Comment: Guess you should take a look at your logical conditions. Inequality sign `=>` should be replaced by `>=`. Also I recomend splitting the two conditions and maybe some parenthesis for readability. Ex. `(5 >= 7) & (7 <= 4)`. In conclusion try to replace the `filter_time` argument in your chunk with `(timestamp >= Blond_prey$New_Time) & (Blond_prey$New_Time <=(Blond_prey&New_Time - 30))`

Comment: Can you create and share a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).